# How do I switch to constant movement when holding down a key in pygame?

Tags: pygame, python-3.5

The following code is set so when the avatar is blitted to the screen and the space bar or up key is tapped it moves once but when it is held down it isn't constantly moved up (in the air). I need to change my code so when the key is held down the move is constant.

```
import pygame, sys, time, random
from pygame.locals import *

class Player(Duck):
    """The player controlled Duck"""


    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        super(Player, self).__init__(x, y, width, height)

        # How many pixels the Player duck should move on a given frame.
        self.y_change = 0
        # How many pixels the spaceship should move each frame a key is pressed.
        self.y_dist = 50


    def MoveKeyDown(self, key):
        """Responds to a key-down event and moves accordingly"""

        if (key == pygame.K_UP or key == K_SPACE):
            self.rect.y -= self.y_dist
    def MoveKeyUp(self, key):
        """Responds to a key-up event and stops movement accordingly"""

        if (key == pygame.K_UP or key == K_SPACE):
            self.rect.y -= self.y_dist


    def update(self):
        """
        Moves the Spaceship while ensuring it stays in bounds
        """
        # Moves it relative to its current location.
        self.rect.move_ip(self.y_change, 0)

        # If the Spaceship moves off the screen, put it back on.
        if self.rect.y <= 0:
            self.rect.y = 0
        elif self.rect.y > window_width:
            self.rect.y = window_width

while True:  # the main game loop
    for event in pygame.event.get(): #Closes game
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            player.MoveKeyUp(event.key)
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            player.MoveKeyDown(event.key)
```

Comment: even though it was closed as off topic, the answers should be of assistance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43154793/in-pygame-why-can-i-not-move-my-sprite-gradually-while-button-is-held-down/43161906#43161906

Comment: Please provide a [complete but minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We want examples that we can run without adjustments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `MoveKeyDown` method you have to set the `self.y_change` value to the desired speed and not adjust the `self.rect.y` value. The `self.rect.move_ip` call in the `update` method will then move the sprite. You have to call the `update` method every frame in your main while loop.

```
def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
    super(Player, self).__init__(x, y, width, height)
    # How many pixels the Player duck should move on a given frame.
    self.x_change = 0
    self.y_change = 0
    # How many pixels the spaceship should move each frame a key is pressed.
    self.speed = 50

def MoveKeyDown(self, key):
    """Responds to a key-down event and moves accordingly."""
    if key in (pygame.K_UP, pygame.K_SPACE):
        self.y_change = -self.speed

def MoveKeyUp(self, key):
    if key in (pygame.K_UP, pygame.K_SPACE) and self.y_change < 0:
        self.y_change = 0

def update(self):
    self.rect.move_ip(self.x_change, self.y_change)
```